# Org-mode tell paragraph position in subtree

Tags: org-mode

Is there a quick way to show where a paragraph is sitting in the document structure hierarchy?

```
* Chapter 1
...
* Chapter 5
** Section 4
...
paragraph X
```

I would like to tell that `paragraph X` is sitting under `Chapter 5, Section 4` without having to navigate the cursor away from the text.

Comment: There is a built-in function called `org-display-outline-path`, which can be activated interactively with `M-x ...` or can be activated with the `SPC` keyboard shortcut if the cursor is at the beginning of a heading and `org-use-speed-commands` is non-nil.

Comment: @lawlist this is almost correct except `org-display-outline-path` doesn't include the current headline. The question suggests it should.

Comment: Please do not post a solution in the question post. Instead, please post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @jagrg `org-display-outline-path` has support for an [optional argument](https://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/org-display-outline-path.html) to specify whether to include the current headline. one can either evaluate a lisp function interactively, or define a custom function and use `(org-display-outline-path nil t)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not defined correctly. You don't need the code inside the interactive line, and you don't need the hook function. This should work fine I think:

```
(defun org-show-position-in-text () ;; display outline path of hierarchical headings
  (interactive)
  (message (mapconcat #'identity (org-get-outline-path t) "/")))
```

Answer (score 0):

## My half-successful attempt:

```
(defun org-show-position-in-text () ;; display outline path of hierarchical headings
  (interactive (mapconcat #'identity (org-get-outline-path t) "/")))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-show-position-in-text)
```

The above function just about does the job. Only that it throws the error `Wrong type argument: listp` before showing the full path to the heading.

Please refer to @John Kitchin's answer for the correct code.